# android, The constructor MediaController() is undefined

Tags: android, instantiation

I have an android app, working fine with fragments,

I need to show a video from a fragment, but in order to do this, I need to instantiate mediacontroller,

but i get :

```
The constructor MediaController() is undefined
```

here my code:

```
package com.orchard.elasto.custom;

import com.egoclean.elasto.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;


//public class VideoView {

public class VideoViewBox extends Fragment{

    // public MediaController mc;


    private MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_view, container,false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_view, container,false);


           VideoView mVideo = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_viewer);;



        mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideo);

      //Set video link (mp4 format )
//        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.egoclean.elasto/raw/shoulder");

        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getClass().getPackage().getName() + "/" + R.raw.video1);


        mVideo.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideo.setVideoURI(video);
        mVideo.start();






        return view;

    }

}
```

so ,
how to instantiate my media controller?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe,

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: @MaKo, this is right. But you need to call this inside [`onActivityCreated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) of after that method. Calling `getActivity()` before the activity is created will return `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
```

works for me.