# How to play video in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I want to display video in fragment 
I have used this code to play it, it worked

```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quranic_section, container, false);

    VideoView view = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.howtopray;
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    view.start();
```

but i want to add button like play stop resume .. how can I do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `MediaController` with `VideoView`:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quranic_section, container, false);
MediaController mc= new MediaController(getActivity());

VideoView view = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.howtopray;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.setMediaController(mc);
view.start();
```

**Edit**

MediaController constructor takes Context as a parameter. Added getActivity() method to provide Context to MediaController constructor.

Comment: it give an error "The Constructor MediaController is undefined"

Comment: help please "The Constructor MediaController is undefined"

Comment: Problem fixed :D thank you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822843/android-the-constructor-mediacontroller-is-undefined]

Comment: I can't see the controller ( play stop resume .. )